# How to keep symmetry with CSS fluid spacing of dynamic content

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a main content div in which I am dynamically adding blocks of content in a row-style layout (not using tables). I am trying to keep spacing symmetry between the content blocks themselves as well as the edge content blocks and the border of the main content div.

Here is the layout I am trying to achieve:

```
 ______________________________________
|                                      |  
|  |XXXXX|  |XXXXX|  |XXXXX|  |XXXXX|  |  
|  |XXXXX|  |XXXXX|  |XXXXX|  |XXXXX|  |  
|                                      |  
|  |XXXXX|  |XXXXX|  |XXXXX|  |XXXXX|  |  
|  |XXXXX|  |XXXXX|  |XXXXX|  |XXXXX|  |  
|                                      |  
|  |XXXXX|  |XXXXX|  |XXXXX|  |XXXXX|  |  
|  |XXXXX|  |XXXXX|  |XXXXX|  |XXXXX|  |  
|______________________________________|
```

The large container div is my content div.

The small |XXXXXX| blocks are my inner content-block divs.

Here is the issue I run into: when I use margin-left or margin-right to properly space the inner divs it throws off the spacing of the edge blocks with the larger content div - So **i end up with extra space on either that far right or the far left** which makes the page look ugly. I've set the width of the inner blocks to allow for 4 per "row" which is the layout I would like to keep. The total number of inner blocks is dynamically determined by the data in my DB anywhere from 1 to 30.

Here is my code:

```
div.content {
    float: left;
    width: 96%;
    padding: 2%;
}    

div.inner_block {
    float: left;
    width: 22%;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 3% 2% 0;  
}
```

If possible I would like to keep the "padding: 2%" on the content div as that keeps consistency across many other pages that are loaded into this content div.

What do you think? What is the solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your `div.inner_block` to have `margin: 1% 1% 2% 2%;` seems to balance everything nicely.

[**See example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/PQd5J/1/show/)

Answer (score 0):

You only have `width:96%;` to work with. So your calculation `22%+3%` of margin is wrong here since it will make 100% when you have 4 blocks of content inside. But you only have `96%` of your container width to work with.

So to make it simple - your 4 containers should make 96% not 100% of total width because you have padding around.

Remember that `margin+padding+width = total outer width`.